# Maximum number of datapoints allowed in a highcharts/stock series data hash

Tags: highcharts

I seem to be running into some kind of limit to the number of datapoints I can have in my series datahash.  I am creating my data hash like so:

```
var data_hash = [];
var limit = 1000;
for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    data_hash.push({myData:'blah', 
                         x: i, 
                         y: (i+1)});
}

$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s = '';

                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                    s += 'x: '+ point.x;
                    s += ', y: '+point.y;
                });

                return s;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'series_limit',
            data: data_hash
        }]
    });
});
```

If I set the limit variable to 1000 or lower the graph will render just fine.  However if I were to increase it to any value higher than that the graph will stop rendering.  Is there something wrong with the way I am constructing my hash?  Or is there some kind of configuration setting I can change to increase the number of datapoints allowed?

Here is a link to the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hYtUj/13/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default number of datapoints before highcharts starts using arrays is **1000**.You can change this value in chart options([parameter threshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.threshold))

Comment: It was actually the turboThreshhold that I needed to change, but this got me to the right documentation!  Thanks!

Comment: Here is the updated jsfiddle for anyone interested:
http://jsfiddle.net/hYtUj/14/

Answer (score 3):

Set `turboThreshhold` option to 0 or use two dimensional array with x and y values ([turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold))

```
data_hash.push([i+1, i]); // instead of {x: i, y: i+1}
```